# Hover one element, select another

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an element that I am trying to affect with CSS animations.  The problem is that I am almost certain that the code is right to make the animation work.  Perhaps there is something in the code above it that is affecting it through inherited properties, but I cannot seem to find it.

There should be a `<p>` that appears through opacity.

Here is the Codepen [link](http://codepen.io/blue11/pen/syAui)

The code that I used for selecting the elements to animate is below.

```
.wrap:hover div .dropP
```

Answer (score 1):

1. the font color in `p` is the same as background, because there is
   no such property as `font-color: #000;`, it should be just `color`
2. `opacity` of `p` stays the same (0) even on `:hover` due to other rules that you have.

Comment: Cheery, I understand part 1, but I do not understand part 2.  I have went through the code several times.  I don't understand what part is keeping the opacity at (0) despite my hover rule.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Blue `.dropHide, .dropHide p {` (has opacity: 0 !important), `.wrap p {`

Comment: I changed these rules.  I can see the text, but it is not invisible before hover...I am still seeing it.  I have updated the CodePen ( [link](http://codepen.io/blue11/pen/syAui) ).  I really appreciate the help with this!

Comment: @Blue you can hide it, but without `!important`, but unhide id on :hover.

Comment: I have tried that, but it is still not going through.  I updated the CodePen with that change.  I looked at the documentation on w3c, and it says opacity can be used with animation...